# Upgrading from MariaDB 10.2 to MariaDB 10.3 // docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

i did an upgrade on my server for my Docker MARIADB with:

```
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up -d
```

My version before:

Server version: 10.2.14-MariaDB-10.2.14+maria~jessie mariadb.org binary distribution

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";

+-------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                                |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.7.21                               |
| protocol_version        | 10                                   |
| slave_type_conversions  |                                      |
| version                 | 10.2.14-MariaDB-10.2.14+maria~jessie |
| version_comment         | mariadb.org binary distribution      |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                               |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu                     |
| version_malloc_library  | system                               |
| version_ssl_library     | OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016           |
| wsrep_patch_version     | wsrep_25.23                          |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

My version now:
Server version: 10.3.9-MariaDB-1:10.3.9+maria~bionic mariadb.org binary distribution

```
+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value                                    |
+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| innodb_version                  | 10.3.9                                   |
| protocol_version                | 10                                       |
| slave_type_conversions          |                                          |
| system_versioning_alter_history | ERROR                                    |
| system_versioning_asof          | DEFAULT                                  |
| version                         | 10.3.9-MariaDB-1:10.3.9+maria~bionic     |
| version_comment                 | mariadb.org binary distribution          |
| version_compile_machine         | x86_64                                   |
| version_compile_os              | debian-linux-gnu                         |
| version_malloc_library          | system                                   |
| version_source_revision         | ca26f91bcaa21933147974c823852a2e1c2e2bd7 |
| version_ssl_library             | OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017               |
| wsrep_patch_version             | wsrep_25.23                              |
+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

So it seems it was a upgrade from 10.2 to 10.3.
[Upgrading from MariaDB 10.2 to MariaDB 10.3](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/upgrading-from-mariadb-102-to-mariadb-103/)

Now i get the following error in "docker-compose logs"

```
2018-09-28 13:03:38 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_table_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
2018-09-28 13:03:38 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_index_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
```

The database is working as expected. What to do to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While I was writing the question I was able to fix it myself. If you also facing this problem:

1. connect to the docker database container:

   docker exec -u 0 -i -t CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash
2. run mysql_upgrade like written in the error message:

   mysql_upgrade --user=root --password=xxyy --host=localhost
3. I did a restart of the docker compose with:

   docker-compose stop

   docker-compose start

Comment: These days you just need to have `MARIADB_AUTO_UPGRADE=1` as the environment variable on the container and its all automatic on every startup it checks if an upgrade is needed.